# Hide text until HTML element expands to reveal it?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that expands from a height of 50px to 125px upon hovering over it. I want to put some text and an image at the bottom of the div so that it is hidden until the div expands and it is revealed as the expansion rolls over it. This is the expanding syntax I have in CSS:

```
.Home {
height:50px;
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.Home:hover {
height 150px;
}
```

Could anyone help point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: There is a typo in `:hover`, you are missing `:` after `height` in `height 150px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to add overflow:hidden to the .Home class definition. Also add the colon after height in the .Home:hover class.

```
.Home { height:50px;
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: height .5s ease-in-out;
overflow:hidden;
}
```